# PHP Error Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Tags: php, session, header

Hello I have three PHP codes where one page I have is of `index.php` where I am scanning the username and password from the user and then sending it to another file `userlogin_process.php` where I am first starting the session and then I am matching the scanned values with the database and if they match I am storing them into session variable but it shows me 2 warnings on that page Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent and last page I have is of `user_session.php` where I am locating the user to the home page of the website.

index.php

```
session_start();
<form method="post" action="userlogin_process.php">
<div class="p">User Login</div>  
<table style="margin-top:5%;margin-left:12%;">
<tr><td> <label style="font-size:16px"> UserName :</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="input" type="text" name="username" placeholder="FirstName"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><label style="font-size:16px">Password :</label></td></tr>
<tr><td><input class="input" type="password" name="userpass" placeholder="Mobile No"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><input class="button" type="submit" name="usersubmit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**user_loginprocess.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("db.php");
$uname = $_POST['username'];
$upass = $_POST['userpass'];
echo $uname;
echo $upass;
$sql = mysql_query("select id,fname,mobile from user where fname='$uname'") or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if ($count > 0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id = $row['id'];
$fname = $row['fname'];
$mobile = $row['mobile'];
}
}
if( $uname == $fname && $upass == $mobile ){
$_SESSION['uid'] = $id; 
$_SESSION['username'] = $fname;
$_SESSION['usermobile'] = $mobile;
$_SESSION['login'] = "yes";
header('location:user_session.php');
}
else{       
header('location:index.php?msg=incorrect');
} 
?>
```

**user_sesssion.php**

```
<?php 
 session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['login']) == "yes"){
header('location:user_detail.php?pageno=1');
} 
else{   
header('location:index.php?msg=login');
}
 ?>
```

Comment: wow i can do a lot with the names of the file, can you post the related code?

Comment: this may helps you stackoverflow.com/questions/8812754/cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-headers-already-sent

Comment: use `ob_start()` at the first line

Comment: there where two warnings at the top of the page and at the end of the page but as per ur advice i have added ob_start by your grace the first warning has been cleared but same warning is still there at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i can see is that you use `session_start()` multiple times. as you can see it in their [docs](https://www.php.net/session_start) that will not create any harm but it may throw an error or warnings.. so it is better to stick to use only once.

Second please use `mysqli_*` *[docs](https://www.php.net/mysqli)* since `my_sql` is deprecated. or [PDO](https://www.php.net/PDO).

and this part looks off::

```
session_start();
<form method="post" action="userlogin_process.php">
```

it should be:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<form method="post" action="userlogin_process.php">
```

but either way is wrong since session should be stared in top of the page.  and last try to fix all those small mistakes, it may work or throw another error, which in either case is good, since is moving forwards :)

Answer (score 0):

To stop sending header very early it is good to buffer output and send at the end of script. For this turn on buffering in php.ini.

```
output_buffering = On
```